# SSRS : show value in text box as per the label name column value

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

I have four text boxes and each need to have a unique value as per the label name.

First will have the value as per `Overdue` label name, second will have value for `next1` `label_name` and so on.

Below expression I have tried, but not able to achieve it.

```
=iif(First(Fields!Label_name.Value,"DataSet1") = "Overdue"
    ,First(Fields!Label_value.Value, "DataSet1")
    ,0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression served my requirement.

```
=Lookup("Overdue"
       ,Fields!Label_name.Value
       ,Fields!Label_value.Value
       ,"DataSet1"
       )
```